# SSH/Cron services hangs on RHEL 8.6

Tags: ssh, rhel, cron, openssh

So, i have an odd issue with my VM RHEL 8.6 test server with Hyper-V.

The problem is the SSH Service hangs from time to time, around midnight.

To connect again to the server i have to Reboot it manually in Hyper-V, cuz i cant login through SSH as it is freezed.

The weird thing, other services are running fine, ie. httpd, mysqld and others.

I have telnet, ping, nmap (port 22 open), snmp responses, everything looks fine except for the SSH.

There is a Nagios 4.4.7 installed, and when the SSH freeze happens, also the Services Checks by Nagios stops.

I have another server with Nagios monitoring the problematic server, snmp is working fine and i can see CPU and RAM ok too.

When i try to log in with SSH i get no response... but with Debug Level it seems that it can connect but it wont move forward.

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2 (CentrifyDC build 5.1.3-204) (CentrifyDC build 5.1.3-204), OpenSSL 0.9.8w-fips 23 Apr 2012
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: Connecting to 10.85.x.x [10.85.x.x] port 22.
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: Connection established.
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug3: Could not load "/home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: identity file /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: identity file /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: identity file /home/nagios/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: identity file /home/nagios/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: identity file /home/nagios/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: identity file /home/nagios/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
2023-04-08 12:04:17:    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2

[root@hostname ~]#  nmap -sU -p 22 10.85.x.x

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2023-04-08 12:09 BOT
Nmap scan report for 10.85.x.x
Host is up (0.0050s latency).
PORT   STATE         SERVICE
22/udp open|filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.38 seconds

[root@hostname ~]# telnet 10.85.x.x 22
Trying 10.85.x.x...
Connected to 10.85.x.x.
```

and this from a newer host with RHEL 8.6

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 10.85.x.x originally 10.85.x.x
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.85.x.x is address
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 10.85.x.x originally 10.85.x.x
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.85.x.x [10.85.x.x] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.85.x.x port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 10.85.x.x port 22: Connection refused
```

Also another thing is, cron jobs stop working too, i have a local script to reboot automatically if somehow a file stop updating but it wont run when SSH service is freezed.

That means that is not running any cron jobs really, im not an expert but this depends on SSH or what else could be the reason to not execute these tasks?

I have disabled mysqld, ndo2db and still the hangs persists.

Tell me where to start so i can figure it out haha, thanks!

Comment: Figure out a way (that depends on what hyper-v can offer) to access remotely its *console*. When a system can't be reached by network but appears to be running, that's usually the thing to do. Also the last test (connection refused) is not consistent with the other tests (connection established/connected to).

Comment: Another option is to log in and keep that session alive. When the ssh service dies it is likely that you session will still be active and you can debug from there. Also, have you checked the system logs for any error messages?

Comment: Check space used on the root file system.  If it fills then new processes may hang while exisiting ones would continue running until something gets written requiring more space.    Also check the system log for memory shortages.